# Entity Framework connection string is being rewritten when website is published

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When publish a MVC website via Visual Studio it rewrites the connection string for Entity Frameworks with an invalid one.

It appears to be the same invalid one it created when I first imported the database model (not code first)  The correct connection string is in my local web.config, and there are no changes being made by the web.release.config file.

Correct connection string:

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MODModels.csdl|res://*/Models.MODModels.ssdl|res://*/Models.MODModels.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=R4S-MOD;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Generated connection String:

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=R4S-MOD;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: If you're publishing to Azure (or most hosting providers), the connection string is set on your hosting management dashboard and the connection string in your web.config isn't used.

Comment: Dedicated Windows 2008-R2 Server running IIS7

Comment: do you publish debug or release ? do you have a different web.config for public and release ?

Comment: I do a release publish.  If I do a preview changes to web.config, it shows the connection string being changed to the incorrect string.  The only action in the web.release.config is 
<compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />

Comment: When you do a release publish they should show you a popup where you choose if you want to do filesystem or iis deployment. there is a section in the wizard which has connection string. check it there, if there is already a preselected value for your connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a release publish they should show you a popup where you choose if you want to do filesystem or iis deployment. there is a section in the wizard which has connection string. check it there, if there is already a preselected value for your connection string –  qamar